# Display only Whole number values in ggplotly R

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly, hover, tooltip

I have the following dataframe in R

```
   Data_frame<-data.frame("ID"= c("A","A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B"))
   Data_frame$Val= c(1,1.2,1.4,1.6, 2,2,2.2,2.4,2.6, 3)
   Data_frame$Val2<-Data_frame$Val*2
```

I have created the following chart in R using ggplot and plotly

```
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)
```

I have generated the following  chart

```
plot1<-ggplot(data = Data_frame,  mapping = aes(x = Val, y = Val2, color=str_wrap(ID, 20)))+ 
geom_line()

ggplotly(plot1, dynamicTicks = T)
```

The plot renders and on hover, we can see all the values of the column Val when we hover the cursor on the Chart. Is it possible to ensure that only the whole number values of Val display when we hover. I request someone to help me here. I havent been able to find a solution for this.

Comment: Do you only want to show a tooltip for whole-number values, or do you want to round the reported number to a whole number in every tooltip?

Comment: I would like to show a tooltip for whole number values only. Not Rounded values. is this possible

Answer (score 0):

```
ggplotly(plot1, dynamicTicks = T, tooltip = "x")
```

[image]

Comment: Ah no sir. This only displays x axis ticks. I wantonly the whole number values of x to display. ie 1 and 2 for ID A and 2 and 3 for ID B. The remaining should not render